# Flex: Row index in Datagrid when 'selectable' is set to 'false'

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, itemrenderer, selecteditem

It would be an easy question, but property 'selectable' is set to 'false' and therefore selectedItem is always null.

In each row I have 3 buttons. When I click a button, I need to extract data corresponding to clicked row.

Any ideas how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the MX DataGrid, correct?

In your itemRenderer, reference the listData property and convert it to [DataGridListData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridListData.html).

When the button is clicked dispatch a custom event that includes the [rowIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/BaseListData.html#rowIndex).  You should be able to use the rowIndex to get the selected item out of your dataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

This is my item renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          focusEnabled="true">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var parentView:Object;

            public static function getEditDeleteRenderer(view:Object):ClassFactory{
                var editDeleteRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(EditDeleteRenderer);
                editDeleteRenderer.properties = { parentView:view  };
                return editDeleteRenderer;
            }

            function editItem():void{
                parentView.editItem(data);
            }
            function deleteItem():void{
                parentView.deleteItem(data);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:HBox paddingLeft="5">
        <mx:Image source="assets/edit.png" click="editItem()" />
        <mx:Image source="assets/delete.png" click="deleteItem()" />        
    </mx:HBox>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

This is how I use it

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Activity" width="100" itemRenderer="{EditDeleteRenderer.getEditDeleteRenderer(this)}" />
```

---

```
        public function editItem(foo:Foo){
                    // do edit operation
        }


        public function deleteItem(foo:Foo):void{
                     // do delete operation
        }
```